# Can GWTP Rest Dispatch be used with REST Spring server backend?

Tags: java, spring, rest, gwt, resty-gwt

I've started to use GWTP framework. And I've noticed that it has his own implementation of Rest comunication. I've used to use GWT with RestyGWT And Spring server.

Now I wonder- can I use GWTP Rest Dispatch with Spring server?

Or should I stick with RestyGWT (which is not a part from GWTP).

I haven't found a word about it in official documentation of GWTP. And the example given have in `shared` package rest service interface, which is implemented on `server` side. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWTP REST Dispatch just calls REST URLs, so it doesn't care which implementation is behind the URL, as long as it's reachable by it and returns a proper response. So yes, you are totally fine to use Spring MVC, JAX-RS or anything else for your backend.

Comment: OK. Can You show me so example of client side? I struggle with GWTP documentation, but can make it work. Also the example `carstore` is to complicated to me.

Comment: No, i don't use GWTP, i just had a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use Rest Dispatch with whatever backend you like. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://blog.arcbees.com/2015/10/27/gwtp-beginners-tutorial-toaster-launcher-part-2/) if you'd like more information on how to setup Rest Dispatch. This tutorial was also tested using the Python webapp2 web framework as backend.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good tutorial by the way, but in case of communication I will stick with RestyGwt.